# Postgresql slow query on two indexes combined

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with around 100 million records and the following indexes:

```
 Column        |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  |
---------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer                  | ... pk ...| plain    |
 url           | character varying(500)   | not null  | extended |
 description   | text                     |           | extended |
 domain_id     | integer                  |           | plain    |
 index_status  | integer                  | not null  | plain    |
```

Indexes:

- "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
- "mytable_url_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (url)
- "mytable_662cbf12" btree (domain_id)
- "mytable_id_idx" btree (id) WHERE index_status = 0

I first created the `index_status=0` index because I wanted to query the table with :

```
select * 
from mytable 
where index_status = 0 
limit 1000;
```

and it was working great, but now I also want to query it like this:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where index_status = 0 and domain_id = 233 
limit 1000;
```

So as you can see I am now querying my database with two indexes, and it was working great, because my records related to a `domain_id` were around `50,000`, so it was querying them quite fast (around `1s`).

But now I have records related to a `domain_id` with around `3,000,000` records and it takes around `10` minutes.

how can it be if both fields are indexed? and what should I do to speed up that kind of query? Should I create a new index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filtered index on more than one column:

```
create index idx_mytable_3 on mytable(domain_id, id) where index_status = 0;
```

You can replace `mytable_id_idx` with this one.

Note:  Using `limit` without `order by` is suspicious.  If you want the results in `id` order, you should include `order by id` explicitly.

Comment: I query them and change the `index_status` so the next time I get new ones.